# displaying ranges for acceptable values

Tags: interface, simplicity, intuitive

I need to display information related to room environmental parameters such as temperature, humidity, etc.

For instance, fields for temperature are:

- The actual room temperature.
- The room temperature thermostat setpoint.
- The desired room temperature setpoint. Will ideally be the same as the room temperature thermostat setpoint, but might be different if you forgot to change your thermostat.  Maybe instead of displaying, just display some indication if it is different than the thermostat setpoint?
- The high warning alarm temperature (i.e. if the room raises to this temperature, send out a warning alarm).
- The low warning alarm temperature.
- The high critical alarm temperature.
- The low critical alarm temperature.

How should this information be intuitively presented using a minimum amount of screen space?  Note that I am NOT asking for a design, but aspects such as how to communicate high/low alarms, etc.

Comment: Could you provide more context. what's the device this will be displayed in? mobile or desktop? whats the intended purpose of displaying this etc.

Comment: What is the exact problem? For now I will flag it as too broad.

Comment: @AmeenAkbar  Displaying on a desktop.  The user can view the alarm values, and know that they will get an email if the room temperature goes out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach is greatly different for different scenarios:

- Who your users are? Are they aged people with sight issues?
- What's its intended application? Industrial use or home use?
- Which platform will host this display? Small monochrome LCD screen, computer screen, TV, smartphone, tablet?
- Do you have any space restrictions? What's (typical) screen resolution? Do you have any constraint?
- Is it a passive display or users will need to interact somehow with it? If yes, how? Mouse? Touchscreen?

*Best universal* approach does not exist. You will need to find a compromise according to your specific case.

Let's first take a look to a proof of concept for a *classic* approach to this kind of displays (what you may see, for example, in a power plant monitoring dashboard):

[image: Classic approach 1]

Note that:

1. Here I show a vertical layout but it works also with an horizontal layout. Which one depends on space constraints and screen resolution. If possible I'd keep vertical layout because it's easier - at first sight - to understand high/low while an horizontal layout is *more* affected by culture-related considerations.
2. I'm using only two colors: black for primary information (current temperature) and gray for anything else. You may add (carefully chosen) colors over this but do not rely only on color to carry any useful information. More on this later. Note that sizes and colors depend on your specific scenario (see previous questions), that's why this is just a proof of concept.
3. I have a convention: markers for triggers on left and user selection on the right. Because of their number and their positioning you don't need to differentiate between warning/alert, high/low threshold and desired temperature. It's obvious, you save space and you don't add *noise*.
4. You may want to show thermostat temperature and desired room temperature, I simply added text to show it's different (if you need more then I'd suggest to trigger a warning).
5. I do not repeat temperature unit (°C in this case), it's clearly visible once and obviously all the other numbers have same unit.
6. I didn't do it in this mock but you may want to show desired temperature under actual one (with a slightly smaller font and muted color). With this approach you may omit an indicator (simplifying layout).

Let's see few open details. Current temperature marker can be different and be colored to highlight warnings and alerts (but this is not not the point of your question):

[image: Current temperature indicator - detail]

---

All that said...I have to ask another question. **Do you need to show all these details in the same display?** Do your users need it? If it's a home thermostat I doubt they need (and they want) so many information.

If you can simplify then you may arrive to one of these two:

[image: Compact approach]

You can read ranges in left-right-up-down: upper warning, upper alert, lower warning, lower alert (note upper thresholds are on the top). You can also read ranges up-down-left-right: upper warning, lower warning, upper alert, lower alert (note warnings are on the left and errors on the right). It should be a simple **conceptual model** to understand even without instructions (because numbers are self-explanatory).

Again note that I'm not using color and text size, position and brightness differentiate presented values. Disposition (in second example) may vary according to culture-related considerations. Warnings may be simply highlighted flashing text and using reverse:

[image: Compact approach with warning]

Different layouts are possible (also to include informative icons):

[image: Compact approach with different layout]

When desired and current temperature are the same you may simply omit second line of text.

---

Which approach is better? First one has many disadvantages, for example it conveys many data and it uses a lot space. However it gives you at first sight a clear indication about *where you are* and *where you are going* (and it may accommodate even more data). Second approach is more compact and suite better for low-resolution LCD displays (abandoning gray text in favor of a monochrome approach).

The other point is where/how alarm have to stay. If it's not absolutely necessary then I'd keep them out of sight (unless an alarm is actually on, first example in second approach)...

Comment: Thanks Adriano,  Great post!  My user group is animal technicians who are not tech savvy.  The GUI is a building automation system, and doesn't allow as much customization that I would like.  Let me spend a little more time digesting your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Usually (for dashboards) I like a master-details approach: a compact control (current temperature vs desired temperature) eventually highlighted if warning/alert (blinking, reverse colors/red background or border) and one click to drill down an extended view (depending on application it may be overlapped).another dashboard (details) with extended controls. Usually (at first sight) charts aren't useful for such static parameters: I just want to know if it's OK or not...